# Locally constant (homotopy) pre-factorization algebras

Tags: homotopy-theory, model-categories, homotopy-limits

In my thesis, I'm using the theory of (homotopy) factorization algebras and particularly locally constant ones. While reading an article that I can't find again I read that already a locally constant *pre*-factorization algebra $F$ is automatically a homotopy factorization algebra. For me locally constant means that when $U\subseteq V$ are homeomorphic to disks in $\mathbb R^n$, then $F(U)\rightarrow F(V)$ is a quasi-isomorphism of chain complexes.

The base manifold $M$ is a *smooth* manifold in the case I'm interested in.

My motivation (which is far from an argument) is that we can refine a Weiss (or factorizing) open cover of $U$ to a good Weiss open cover $\mathcal W$ of by breaking each element in the Weiss cover into disks (i.e. subsets homeomorphic to disks). Then the homotopy cosheaf condition became that $F(U)$ is quasi-isomorphic to the homotopy colimit of a constant diagram, where the $n$-th object is $\coprod_{U_1,\cdots,U_n\in\mathcal W}F(U_1\cap\cdots\cap U_n)$ and $U_1\cap \cdots\cap U_n$ are disks.

As I said, my motivation is very far from an actual argument, so if someone has a real proof (or counterexample or a reference), that would be great.

**Edit**: Ok, the comment by Dmitri made (nice counterexample too) me realize that I haven't specified that the pre-factorization algebras that I'm working with are lax monoidal in the sense that given disjoint open subsets $U_1,\cdots,U_n$, the map $$F(U_1)\otimes\cdots\otimes F(U_n)\rightarrow F(U_1\sqcup\cdots\sqcup U_n)$$ is an isomorphism. So my follow-up question is: Does this new detail affect the validity of the claim? As Dmitri points out, without the above extra condition, the claim is definitely not true.

Comment: For a simple counterexample, consider the case when M is the disjoint union of two points.  Then the local constancy condition is always true.  A prefactorization algebra on M is two objects A, B assigned to the two connected components, together with a map A⊗B→C.  For a factorization algebra, the latter map must be a weak equivalence, which is a stronger condition.

Comment: @DmitriPavlov, thank you for the counterexample. I've edited the question with additional detail about the types of pre-factorization algebras I'm working with, if you know a counterexample for this new situation as well, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: For a counterexample for the updated statement, consider the case when M is the disjoint union of countably many points.  As before, local constancy trivially holds.  A prefactorization algebra on M is a family of objects A_i together with pointings 1→A_i, as well as a map ⨂_i A_i → B, where B is the value on M and ⨂ denotes the infinite monoidal product that uses the pointings of A_i.  A factorization algebra further requires that the latter map is a weak equivalence, which is a stronger condition.

Comment: I see, so the statement seems to be just false. Good to know, thank a lot @DmitriPavlov

Comment: In your updated statement the symmetric monoidal condition allows one to define an excisivity condition for unions of submanifolds. Perhaps the statement you are referring to is saying that a locally constant homotopy prefactorization algebra which satisfies excision is a factorization algebra?

Comment: @ConnorMalin, I don't remember the article mentioning excision, I think it was actually the statement that Dmitri simply disproved. The statement with excision might be true, not sure. How would you phrase this excisivity property?

Comment: One has to show that if an open of $M$ is homeomorphic to $N \times (0,\infty)$ its value under a locally constant pre factorization algebra canonically an $A_\infty$ algebra. Similarly, if there is a codimension 0 submanifold $W$ with boundary $N$ its value forms a module over the algebra associated to $N$. If $M$ is a union $W \cup_N Z$, then it can be compared to the derived tensor product of the modules associated to $W,Z$ over the algebra associated to $A$. Excision is the requirement that this is an equivalence.

Comment: @ConnorMalin, I see. I didn't even think about such a concept. So, to me it reads like a "this factorization algebra preserves pushout", is that correct?

Comment: @AlessandroNanto Essentially yes, but it is a more general property. If the symmetric monoidal structure is given by the coproduct, then I believe this should be equivalent to sending nice pushouts of manifolds to homotopy pushout outs. In general though, it is something that requires the symmetric monoidal product to state and is not purely categorical.

Comment: I think the article you mention is [this set of notes](https://arxiv.org/abs/1307.5213). (See around Remark 24 on page 43). There Ginot states that homotopy Disk-prefactorization algebra (a prefactorization algebra defined only on disks) can essentially uniquely be extended to a homotopy factorization algebra. (I must agree that his remark on page 37, right after Definition 14, is a bit confusing. )

Comment: @Ken I don't think that was the article, but the Remark you're referencing seems to be exactly what I need. I'll have a look, thanks.